# (Grafana / Kibana / Elasticsearch) Table to display count of specific values by endpoint

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana, grafana, dashboard

I've set up a Grafana table, where I can log/display all the exceptions thrown in a given endpoint.

Now the next thing I want to do is to have a counter for each of the exceptions, shown in a graph or table - is that possible? (not having to "hardcode" every possible exception).

The table I have now looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the table I have now, showing exceptions thrown]

As you can see - some of the exceptions are the same. It could be nice to have an overview, where I can see fx a count of each exception that has been thrown the last 24 hours, making it a great tool to improve the system and prioritize what to work on first.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your field with exception is indexed, you can:

- aggregate data by this field (group by terms)
- get count of every series (metric -> count)

If your field not indexed, you can't do it*

[image: Screenshot of setup for table]

by grouping by exception.Message.keyword it will give a nice table showing a count for each exception.

Notice that if they are not all showing, then try manipulating/changing the last rubric "Top 10, Min Doc Count.." into the "No limit"-option.

*answer found [here (Reddit)](https://www.reddit.com/r/grafana/comments/dte3ne/get_a_count_for_each_exception_message/)